# What's the proper way to listen for changes in Cloud Firestore using Java?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I need help with figuring out how to use Firestore listener. I feel like I miss some very important knowledge here.

I want server to check if new data was added to database, and then do some computation with it.

At this state it will work only once.

When I add endless loop around DocumentReference with additional Thread.sleep(), it outputs data in set intervals, even when it was unchanged. Additionally, when data in database is changed, it outputs new data way more then one time.

Thank you for all help.

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("src/main/java/key.json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("user-data").document("user-data");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(
    new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                return;
            }

            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
            } else {
                System.out.print("Current data: null");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If your app is in the foreground then you should register a snapshotListener on the document or collection of interest. If your app is in the background then this feels like a good case for Cloud Functions, triggered by database changes, then pushing updates to the affected users.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The problem was my missunderstanding of listeners nature. I didn't know they are based on using interrupts. Now that I got it into account, it works properly. Thanks!